# How to display multiple node for xmltype in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I have a column b_xml in table T_XML,

```
T_XML
a_var      b_xml

A1         <amt1>1</amt1><amt2>1.11</amt2><bmt>1.111</bmt>.....
A2         <amt1>2</amt1><amt2>2.22</amt2><bmt>2.222</bmt>....
...
AN         <amt1>n</amt1><amt2>x</amt2><bmt>y</bmt>....
```

I want to transform the xml to csv record.

Is there any query or function I can use to display b_xml as below?

```
amt1,amt2,bmt...


1,1.11,1.111...
2,2.22,2.222...
....
n,x,y,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `XMLTABLE` function to map the result of `XMLType` column into relational rows and columns, and then concatenate the results :

```
SELECT amt1||','||amt2||','||bmt as "Concatenated String"
  FROM XML_TAB x
 CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(XMLnamespaces('http://www.example.com' as "ns"),
                'ns:Root'
                PASSING x.xml_data
                COLUMNS
                    amt1 VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'ns:amt1',
                    amt2 VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'ns:amt2',
                    bmt  VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'ns:bmt'
                    ) t;
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d4dfd114a4ccedd6f90bbbca6d4dab5)</kbd>

or for the case of rendering `XMLType` data without `namespace` option :

```
SELECT amt1||','||amt2||','||bmt as "Concatenated String"
  FROM XML_TAB x
 CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE('/Root'
                PASSING x.xml_data
                COLUMNS
                    amt1 VARCHAR2(255) PATH '/Root/amt1',
                    amt2 VARCHAR2(255) PATH '/Root/amt2',
                    bmt  VARCHAR2(255) PATH '/Root/bmt'
                    ) t;
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6b64c55ccb06e6ec23dbf83f6f970aa)</kbd>